# Stored procedure to insert new records in the child tables

Tags: stored-procedures, triggers, parent-child, greenplum

I'm trying to create a stored procedure to insert new records in a number of child tables (using Greenplum) I have a master table and a set of child tables. I would like to insert new records that I have in the master table into the child tables (I have around 20 child tables). My assumption is that I should create a function, then a trigger.

Note that I only want to insert some fields into the child tables.

I made a few attempts, but here's the last one: (sorry in advance if it looks very bad. I never created any trigger functions)

FUNCTION:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION 
schema1.newcustomerdata() RETURNS trigger AS $new_customer_data$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO schema1.customeridentifiers 
                (customer_id,
                date_time)
        SELECT NEW.customer_id,
                date_time 
        FROM schema1.customersmaster 
        ;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$new_customer_data$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

TRIGGER:

```
CREATE  TRIGGER newcustomerdata 
AFTER INSERT ON schema1.customersmaster 
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE newcustomerdata();
```

The function and trigger runs. However, I can't insert data in the master table anymore.
I get this error message:

> function cannot execute on segment because it issues a non-select statement

So my questions are:

- What would be the best solutions to update the child tables?
- What's wrong with my function or trigger?
- What are your recommendations?

Comment: PostgreSQL 8.2.15 (Greenplum Database 4.3.10.0

Answer (score 0):

Apparently "Triggers are not supported since they typically rely on the use of VOLATILE functions" Use RULES instead of triggers

```
CREATE RULE newcustomerdata  AS ON INSERT TO schema1.customersmaster 
DO also INSERT INTO schema1.customeridentifiers VALUES (NEW.customer_id, NEW.date_time);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. However it gives me another error message. (ERROR: column "date_time" doesn't exist) :(

Comment: is date_time a column from schema1.customersmaster table?

Comment: Yes, this field is part of the master table. And should be used to populate / update the child tables.

Comment: then you can use NEW.date_time . Updated the solution try that

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help but it gives me another error message..  SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: function cannot execute on segment because it issues a non-SELECT statement (functions.c:135) 
  Detail: 
SQL statement "INSERT INTO schema1.customeridentifiers (customer_id,date_time) VALUES ( $1 ,  $2  )"
PL/pgSQL function  at SQL statement

Comment: Apparently "Triggers are not supported since they typically rely on the use of VOLATILE functions" Use RULES instead of triggers. Updated the code for RULES. Use CREATE RULE instead of CREATE TRIGGER and FUNCTION